Spark session thread safety
I'v read that spark session context is thread-safe but not in all cases.
I have multi thread application which is organized so :
N - workers serving event-bus and sending some simple Spark tasks .
Now i want to add job description to each task to make pipeline more observable using something like :
  def withJobDesciption[T](desc:String)(fn: => T)(implicit spark: SparkSession) : T = {
    spark.sparkContext.setJobDescription(desc)
    try {
      fn
    } finally {
      spark.sparkContext.setJobDescription("")
    }
  }

sparkContext looks like global storage and must not be shared between threads. From the other point of view i see in the oficial codebase parts like this :
org/apache/spark/util/HadoopFSUtils.scala

    val previousJobDescription = sc.getLocalProperty(SparkContext.SPARK_JOB_DESCRIPTION)

    val statusMap = try {
      val description = paths.size match {
        case 0 =>
          "Listing leaf files and directories 0 paths"
        case 1 =>
          s"Listing leaf files and directories for 1 path:<br/>${paths(0)}"
        case s =>
          s"Listing leaf files and directories for $s paths:<br/>${paths(0)}, ..."
      }
      sc.setJobDescription(description)

....

    finally {
      sc.setJobDescription(previousJobDescription)
    }

So my question is what is canonical way of setting jobDescription in multi-threaded application and what is a proper way of using spark sessions in this environment ?

The code calls setLocalProperty:
/** Set a human readable description of the current job. */
  def setJobDescription(value: String): Unit = {
    setLocalProperty(SparkContext.SPARK_JOB_DESCRIPTION, value)
  }

setLocalProperty itself gives a handy warning in it's docs:
These properties are inherited by child threads spawned from this thread. This may have unexpected consequences when working with thread pools. The standard java implementation of thread pools have worker threads spawn other worker threads. As a result, local properties may propagate unpredictably.

It's not clear from your description if you would fall foul of this.

I think yes i would fail foul of this .
I am instatiating workers pool with N threads which are sharing spak session.
